# Why is there a difference between >>& and &>>, but NOT >& and &>?

Tags: bash

From the [bash man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), under the section "Redirection":

> **Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error**
>
> This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the file whose name is the expansion of word.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
>
> &>word
>
> and
>
> >&word
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred.

That made me wonder, why is the first preferred? I see that `&>>` works, but `>>&` does not, so the preference makes sense. So why does `>>&` not work? Is it ambiguous?

---

Here's what I'm running

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: On `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`, neither `&>>` nor `>>&` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `&>dest` is unambiguous, whereas `>&dest` looks like `fdup()` syntax ...and can be *construed* as `fdup` syntax when you have a numeric filename.

Bash, since 4.1 or later, allows the destination of a `fdup` operation to be parameterized -- thus, not just `2>&1`, but also `2>&$stderr_fd`. Putting the `&` after the `>` puts us into the namespace of syntax used for `fdup()` operations; keeping it beforehand is unambiguous.

Example: I want to redirect the stdout and stderr of the command `cmd` into my file. If my file's name is `0`, `>&` causes issues.

- `cmd >& 0` becomes `cmd 1>&0`. That is, redirect stdout to fd#0.
- `cmd &> 0` becomes `cmd > 0 2>&1`. That is, redirect stdout to the file named `0`, then redirect stderr to fd#1.

---

#### `[n]>&word` is POSIX-standardized; `&>word` is not found anywhere in the POSIX standard.

The only forms for duplicating existing file descriptors [defined by the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_05) are `[n]<&word` and `[n]>&word`. In the grammar, these are given the token names `GREATAND` and `LESSAND`.

There are no POSIX-defined tokens for `&>` or `&<` – they are merely syntactic sugar for the commonly used operation of "I don't want to see anything on my screen", or "send stdout and stderr to a file".

This is useful, because `cmd 2>&1 > myFile` - surprisingly to those new to bash - doesn't work as intended for the "clean screen" goal, whereas `cmd > myFile 2>&1`, *does*.

---

So.. why does `&>>` work when `>>&` does not? Because whoever wrote `&>>` didn't feel the need to create an ambiguity, and consciously chose to not allow `>>&`.

#### `fdup()` synonyms with `>>` would not add value.

To explain a bit more about *why* `[n]>&word` synonyms are pointless -- keep in mind that the difference between `>bar` and `>>bar` is the presence of the `O_APPEND` flag and absence of `O_TRUNC` in the `flags` argument to `open()`. However, when you're providing a file descriptor number -- and thus performing an `fdup()` from an old FD number to a new one -- *the file is already open*; the flags thus cannot be changed. Even the direction -- `>` vs `<` -- is purely informational to the reader.

Comment: I failed to mention that I'm reading the part of the man page from "Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error", a subsection of "Redirection". &>word is syntactic sugar for >word 2>&1. I'm going to update my question

Comment: The semantics of this are subtle... the special case of `>&` and `&>` perform 2 redirections, sending both stdout and stderr to the file. The syntax of `>&` is too similar to the actual bash redirection language, `old_out_fd>&new_out_fd`, and thus can be confusing. Whereas the `&>`, with its deliberate swapping of order, cannot be confused as easily.

Comment: Yes, I agree that those things are true, but I thought the answer already made them clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177522/discussion-between-ari-sweedler-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: Re `cmd 2>&1 >myFile`, redirections are processed left-to-right; so in that order, you first make FD 2 point to the original FD 1, then you change FD 1. If FDs 1 and 2 pointed to the same destination in the first place, then `2>&1` did nothing.